# Select, Sum and compare with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, select, compare

I have two tables in my MySQL database:

1 named "stock"

```
id | product | qty
----------------------
1  |     1      | 15
----------------------
2  |     1      | 20


And the second one named "orders"
id | product | qty | stock_id
----------------------------
1  |    1    |  7  |   1
-----------------------------
2  |    1    |  8  |   1
```

So, before register a new "order", I need to verify which "stock.id" has free product to sell, with SUM all existent orders.qty and subtract it to stock.qty, for this example I'm going to insert a new order of 10 pieces of product with id '1' ($new_order = '10' (pieces):

> for each stock.id { SUM(orders.qty) as total | then verify if 'total' >= $new_order | if(total >= $new_order){select that stock.id} if don't { continue looking for an stock.id with free product for sale }   }

Hoping to make myself known, I need your help to structure MySql query from PHP for that function.

---

UPDATE

I've solved with this double query:

```
<?
$queryL = "SELECT id,unidades,producto FROM stock WHERE `producto` = '$producto'";
    $resultL = $mysqli->query($queryL);
    /* array asociativo */
    while($rowL = mysqli_fetch_array($resultL, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        $id_lote = $rowL['id'];
        $unidades = $rowL['unidades'];

    $queryD = "SELECT SUM(cantidad) as total FROM `pedidos` WHERE `lote` = $id_lote";
    $resultD = $mysqli->query($queryD);
    /* array asociativo */

    if($rowD = mysqli_fetch_array($resultD, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $ventas = $rowD['total'];

        $disponible = $unidades - $ventas;

        if($disponible >= $cantidad){ $lote = $id_lote; }

    }
    }
?>
```

Can someone help me simplifying this?

Comment: Is the `product` column the name of a certain product?

Comment: no, it's just an ID from another table :)

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) 
if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and 
provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Read [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Updated !!! I've just wrote a working code, there is a way to make it work with just one query??